# Css doesnt get rendered in fat free framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

appreciate anybody who can help in this - i cannot see my css styling in browser view:

using f3:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
  function ($f3) {
    $f3->set('html_title','XXX Home');
    $f3->set('content','homepage.html');
    echo Template::instance()->render('layout.html');
  }
);
```

my layout.html (all my css is in a "css" folder) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>{{ @html_title }}</title>
    <!-- PLUGIN STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/responsive.gs.12col.css" />

    <!-- THEME STYLESHEETS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/shortcodes.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/responsive.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/css/color.css" />

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT PLUGINS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/modernizr.custom.97074.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <include href="{{ @content }}" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console of the browser debugger?

Comment: Loading failed for the <script> with source “..../scripts/jquery.1.11.1.min.js”.

Comment: Have you placed that file (and the other css/js files) at that location on your server?

Comment: BTW, jQuery 1.11 is ancient. It would be a very bad idea to use it. As a beginner it would be a good idea to avoid jQuery altogether and first learn to use JavaScript without it.

Comment: Yes I have placed them in that location so I'm not sure why it is still not rendered.

Comment: What does the structure of the htdocs directory look like?

Comment: dont use absolute paths in your css files.i.e.: `css/theme.css` not `/css/theme.css`.. and add a `<base href="">` tag to your head to compensate for subdirectories

Comment: You should prepend css and script path with `{{@BASE}}`, e.g. `{{@BASE}}/css`